# Is it mandatory to have check In/Check Out on library to appear documents in search result

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I've used SharePoint Search(Mostly Content Search WebParts) through out the SharePoint Online site. I used check-In/Check-Out with Publish feature on all the document libraries to have the updated content in search result.

I want to know whether it is necessary to have this publishing functionality onto the documents to appear them in Search results.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Akram

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have check-in/check-out enabled in your libraries.  The document just needs to be available to the user for it to appear in their results.  So if it's enabled, it needs to be checked in and published.  If it's not enabled, once the search crawler finds your document and indexes it, it should appear.